# Sorting alphabetically using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, alphabetical

How can I sort a csv file using pandas so that the names are sorted the same way finder does it?

In finder I have millions of files named as such: "-2odhDKSZ22302_000.jpg". These file names are also in a csv. I'd like to be able to go through the images via finder and the csv file in the same order.

If there are differences in how other operating systems (e.g. Ubuntu) sort file names could you please point this out.

Update: `sort_values()` has a `key` argument, if I knew what the default method of sorting was for the operating systems then I could match them up.

I've tried searching on stack sites but can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: @e-motta No, I have used sort_values() on the csv. My question is what is the method for sorting, e.g. how does it deal with special characters, numbers, capitalization etc. I would like the method to match with the operating system I use. For example, if I sort from A-Z using Files on Ubuntu.

Comment: Python will sort according to codepoint order. If you use the `key` parameter you can tailor the sort to your requirements.